# Object-literal filled with Object3Ds - loop to populate with meshes

Tags: javascript, loops, three.js, mesh, object-literal

I'm trying to populate an object-literal with Three.js `Object3D`s and then populate the `Object3D`s with meshes. However I'm getting some strange results from my code. I've distilled the problem to the barest lines of code that still replicate the problem. In the scenario below thing1 and thing2 receive no meshes and thing3 receives all three meshes:

```
var objSet = {
    thing1: new THREE.Object3D(),
    thing2: new THREE.Object3D(),
    thing3: new THREE.Object3D()
};

for (key in objSet) {
    objSet[key].add(aMesh);
    objSet[key].add(anotherMesh);
    objSet[key].add(yetAnotherMesh);
};
```

My eventual goal is to dynamically create an object-literal filled with `Object3D`s an then reliably loop through and add meshes to each. Where is the problem here? Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj - I simplified my earlier question and reposted it here. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: That's because in the last iteration of the `for...in` loop, `key` is `thing3`, so you are adding all three meshes to `objSet.thing3`. It looks like you want to explicitly set `objSet.thing1.add(aMesh); objSet.thing2.add(anotherMesh); ...`. Or you should create an array of objects and an array of meshes and then match them by their index.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks for your response. This is likely really basic, but why is it not adding the meshes to `thing1` and `thing2` as well, as the loop runs it's course?

Comment: @FelixKling - This is a toy example; there will be several hundred of these in the final program (an animation) so explicit assignment is out. Two arrays is doable but a little cumbersome. Any guesses why I've not been able to keep the `Object3D`s and meshes successfully in the same object-literal?

Comment: Oh, do you actually want to add all three meshes to each element? I don't know three.js very well, but I guess a mesh can only belong to one object. So if you add the meshes to `thing3`, they get removed from `thing2`. If you want to add each mesh to each of the objects, you probably have to create a copy of the meshes.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct.

Comment: @FelixKling -  Ah! I see. I had no idea they were a useable-only-once kind of deal. I'll try recoding that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the guidance of the folks above in the comments, I discovered that the reason for the strange behavior in my code (the console.logs indicated that each `Object3D` in the object-literal was being filled with meshes during the run, but at the end all but the last `Object3D` were empty) was that meshes can be used only once and I needed to copy them into the `Object3Ds`, otherwise they were simply jumping from one to the next as I assigned them. Oi!

The fix was quick and easy - simply add `.clone()` to the end of the mesh variable in the `.add()` function:

```
var objSet = {
    thing1: new THREE.Object3D(),
    thing2: new THREE.Object3D(),
    thing3: new THREE.Object3D()
};

for (key in objSet) {
    objSet[key].add(aMesh.clone());
    objSet[key].add(anotherMesh.clone());
    objSet[key].add(yetAnotherMesh.clone());
};
```

Thanks all!